# How to avoid historic data while reading from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-functions

I'm using the `Azure function App` hosted on (`App Service Plan`) to read the data from `Kafka Topics`.

What I noticed is, when I run the function for the first time, It reads all the millions of historical data which were published over kafka.

In my case, I want to start reading Kafka data from a `specific point in Time`. Is there any way available for this?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660772/ignoring-historic-kakfa-topic-data-in-kafka-triggered-azure-function/

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your app, you need to call `consumer.seek` method.

Or pre-define your consumer group and use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` command to do the same.

Depending on the client you're using, there is an `offsetsForTime` method that you can use before seeking partitions to the offsets values that method returns.

Comment: What if we don't get partition info from the producer?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You don't need any producer information in order to seek a consumer or use the other methods mentioned.

Comment: Got it. One more Question. Which approach is better to read from Kafka? `Azure Function App Trigger` or `.Net Background Service?`